# Regex to white-spaces, hyphen and semicolon

Tags: java, regex

I'm in doubt on how to do an regex, to break an string in all white-spaces, hyphen and semicolon, it's in Java. I'm doing:`String[] tmp = input.nextLine().split("\\s:-");`

but it's not working, which is the right way ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're currently splitting on all three of them in a row. Try character classes, which picks out any one from the selection:

`String[] tmp = input.nextLine().split("[\\s:\\-]");`

(hyphens have meaning in character classes, so you should escape them, too.)